# Normalizing 2D lines in Eigen C++

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

A line in the 2D plane can be represented with the implicit equation

```
  f(x,y) = a*x + b*y + c = 0
         = dot((a,b,c),(x,y,1))
```

If a^2 + b^2 = 1, then f is considered *normalized* and f(x,y) gives you the Euclidean (signed) distance to the line.

Say you are given a 3xK matrix (in Eigen) where each column represents a line:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float,3,Eigen::Dynamic> lines;
```

and you wish to normalize all K lines. Currently I do this a follows:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < K; i++) {    // for each column
   const float s = lines.block(0,i,2,1).norm();    // s = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)
   lines.col(i) /= s;    // (a, b, c) /= s
}
```

I know there must be a more clever and efficient method for this that does not require looping. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The following turns out being slower for optimized code... hmmm..

```
 Eigen::VectorXf scales = lines.block(0,0,2,K).colwise().norm().cwiseInverse()
 lines *= scales.asDiagonal()
```

I assume that this as something to do with creating KxK matrix `scales.asDiagonal()`.

P.S. I could use [Eigen::Hyperplane](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Hyperplane.html) somehow, but the docs seem little opaque.

Comment: > that does require looping. Didn't you mean "that does **not** require looping"?

Comment: Correct -- I'll edit.

Comment: asDiagonal() actually does not create a KxK matrix. It creates a diagonal matrix object, which only stores diagonal elements

Comment: @Solon I am sort of suspicious as to what `asDiagonal()` is really doing ... I am mystified as to why the non-looping version is slower when optimized. Maybe I should convert that to a single line...

Comment: @wcochran, that's most probably because you create a temporal matrix object, as lines *= scales can not be evaluated in-place